# How do I split the keywords from the column, and create a new dataframe with all the values?

Tags: pandas, split

I have the following, a dataframe on the input:

```
data = {'key': ['some of the words', 'something else', 'and more one'], 'values': [3, 4, 4]} 
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

From each key, I want to get a separate word, while keeping in it, the value of the column value. As a result, I want to process the first dataframe in such a way that I get this:

```
data = {'key': ['some', 'of', 'the', 'words', 'something', 'else', 'and', 'more', 'one'], 'values': [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]} 
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
data["key"] = data.key.str.split()
data = data.explode("key")
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
         key  values
0       some       3
0         of       3
0        the       3
0      words       3
1  something       4
1       else       4
2        and       4
2       more       4
2        one       4
```